# Laravel Cache: invalid data

Tags: caching, laravel

I have two functions that look pretty much the same and are called right one after another as AJAX-requests from a JavaScript function.

```
/**
     * get all Airports for autocomplete
     */
    public function getAirports(){
        if(Cache::has('airports')){
            return Cache::get('airports');
        }

        $airportModel = new Airport;

        $airports = json_encode($airportModel -> _getForAutocomplete('iata_faa_code'));

        Cache::put('airports', $airports, 600);

        return $airports;
    }

    /**
     * get all Countries for autocomplete
     */
    public function getCountries(){
        if(Cache::has('countries')){
            return Cache::get('countries');
        }

        $countryModel = new Country;

        $countries = json_encode($countryModel -> _getForAutocomplete('two_letter_code'));

        Cache::put('countries', $countries, 600);

        return $countries;
    }
```

Now when I go to the page for the first time, I get the data correctly (since it has not been cached yet). If I go to the page for the second time, I get the countries but for the airports I get following error and cannot see why.

`{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Encryption\\DecryptException","message":"Invalid data.","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\Encrypter.php","line":132}}`

I have found out, that it has to do something with Cache by Googling and removing the Cache-part. I would be very glad if somebody could help me out with that one.

By the way, I am using the database as my cache driver.

Best regards, Marcel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe there is something fishy going of with serialization. it can be possible that the $airports gets corrupted during serialization.

If the airports string value is too long for MySQL field then end will be silently truncated and decryption of data fails.

By default Laravel recommends the value field type to be text. To make it bigger you can use mediumText or longText fields.

Comment: I don't get into the if-block. If I do `dd(Cache::get('airports'))` or `dd(Cache::has('airports'))` before the if-block, I get the same error

Comment: In this case I recommend to clear the DB cache manually and inspect the json string written into the DB and if it is exactly same in the DB as well.  Might be that something goes wrong in json_encode

Comment: How can I compare it to the string in the DB? In the DB it is supposed to be encrypted

Comment: You can use $value = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted); for decrypting an encrypted string.

Comment: I got the same error, when doing the decryption. So maybe the decryption part causes the error?

Comment: Very likely. You can try manually adding countries json to Cache in getAirports function and/or add manual strings for testing decryption/encryption during Caching

Comment: Indeed, when running `Cache::put('airports', '[{id:1,name:"GKA"},{id:2,name:"MAG"}]', 600);` and then decrypting, I get the correct result

Comment: maybe the data I want to store is too much? I got 8300 airports and only 225 countries

Comment: use mediumText or longText instead of text as the field value.